# Python Tkinter : Control/set the (Tab key) widget "visit" order

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, widget

Widget "visit" (tab key) order is determined by the order of widget creation.  Is there a simple, pure Python (3.x) way to force the widgets to be visited in a different, user-determined order?    If not, is there a simple "Tk" way of doing this?    *(BTW, This is about about widgets, not notebook tabs).*

I couldn't find anything about how to do this while researching the usual tkinter sites, on stackoverflow  etc.  Have I missed something basic, a widget parameter,  universal method, etc.?

Example of why this ability is needed:
The python code (an application/package/class) uses several different widget types and implemented as several files.  The definition/creation of all widgets of the same type, e.g. checkboxes, are placed (isolated) inside their own file (e.g. there is a Checkbox file, a Notebook file, a Button File, etc).  At initialization this organization causes all occurances of one widget type to be created (and thus tab-ordered) sequentially - and before/after any widgets of any other type.
 The resulting widget "visit" order is not (from the users viewpoint) the natural order.  How can I force the natural order without resorting to changing the order of widget creation (or doing somethlng as kludgey/artificial as placing every widget in it's own frame and then arranging the frame creation order to match the natural order)?

Comment: @Mike-SMT thanks for the idea but I'm unfamiliar with "costume event handlers" - at least by that term. Can you provide a web link to some documentation about them?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant "custom". Its can be as simple as a function that performs a task any time an event is triggered. Like someone pressing the tab key. You would use the `bind()` method to bind an event to a widget/frame/window and then when that event triggers it will call a function/method that you wrote. You can have anything happen that you can program in.

Comment: Does this question and answer help, or are you asking something different? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6687108/7432

Comment: That happens to the best of us. I can see I'lI have to do some thinking about the idea as it may have possibiities (but I still find it quite strange that there isn't a simpler way to do it). I've never written a custom event handler but have used custom widget validations (focusin, etc.) and event bindings (<KeyPressed>) so it's probably not a great stretch.  I'll go back to New Mexico Tech and read about them; can you suggest any other web resouces?

Comment: _"I still find it quite strange that there isn't a simpler way to do it"_ - that depends on your definition of "simple". There are certainly other ways. For example, you can create your own binding for the tab key that does whatever you want. Personally I find that creating a list which represents the order I'm interested in is pretty simple. I also find it pretty simple to create the widgets in the order that the user wants to traverse them. Fortunately, Tkinter is extremely flexible; it works right out of the box for the normal case but can be fully customized for the exceptional case.

Comment: To @BryanOakley - my thanks (again), that approach should work. I had seen that question but didn't really understand it till now.  Didn't help that I missed lift/lower in the documentation (their function, given their names, are rather non-descriptive - I'll be doing some more reading about them at the NMT site).  There is also the issue of the huge number of widgets that need to be manually/expliclty reordered.  But that has to be done regardless of method used - making your answer to that question probably the best (most flexable) approach the problem.