# Changing Tab Order of Frames in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

## Summary

How do I `lift` (`tk_raise`) the tab order widgets contained in one frame above the widgets contained in another frame, which was created first?

## Full Version

I have a Tkinter form, for which I am grouping multiple widgets in frames and then am positioning the frames into the window using a grid layout. In my specific use case, the frames are classes derived from `ttk.Frame`, but that doesn't make any difference to this question, as it has no impact on form behavior for the purposes of this question.

For my use case, it makes sense to create multiple frames in a loop, in order to avoid code duplication. As expected, the tab order for the widgets is the order, in which they were created. However, the natural flow for the form in this case, is to tab between widgets in the following order: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), below).

Doing a `lift` on the frame containing widgets 10-12 doesn't change the tab order. However, doing individual lifts on widgets 10-12 generates the following exception:

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't raise ".tabtest.frame_2.widget_10" above ".tabtest.frame_1.widget_5
```

This should be doable, but how?

### Edit

As noted in the comments (below), this may at a first glance appear to be a duplication of the question ["How to set the tab order in a tkinter application?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687108/how-to-set-the-tab-order-in-a-tkinter-application). I reviewed this question prior to submitting mine. However, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6781700/1843248) to this question specifically references setting tab order for widgets within a single frame. When I run the example included in the answer, it works as expected. However, when applying it to my use case:

- Attempting to lift the frame causes no change in tab behavior.
- Attempting to lift the individual widgets contained in the frame generates the error noted above.

## MCVE

Written using Python 3.4.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class TabTest(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        # Remove row/column weights.
        for i in range(50):
            self.rowconfigure(i, weight=0)
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight=0)

        # Entry fields.
        frames = []
        entries = []

        x = 0
        for i in range(2):
            f = ttk.Frame(self, takefocus=0, name='frame_{}'.format(i))
            for j in range(5):
                e = ttk.Entry(f, name='widget_{}'.format(x))
                entries.append(e)
                e.insert(tk.END, 'Widget {}'.format(x))
                e.pack(side='top', anchor='w')
                x += 1

            frames.append(f)

        # Buttons
        buttons = []
        f = ttk.Frame(self, takefocus=0, name='frame_2')
        for i in range(3):
            b = ttk.Button(f, text='Widget {}'.format(x),
                           name='widget_{}'.format(x))  
            buttons.append(b)
            b.pack(fill='x')
            x += 1

        frames.append(f)

        frames[0].grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=5, columnspan=2,
                       padx=2, pady=2, sticky='news')
        frames[2].grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=5, columnspan=2,
                       padx=2, pady=2, sticky='news')
        frames[1].grid(row=0, column=4, rowspan=5, columnspan=2,
                       padx=2, pady=2, sticky='news')

        frames[2].lift()  # No difference in tab order.
#         for btn in buttons:
#             btn.lift(entries[5])  # Generates exception: _tkinter.TclError: can't raise ".tabtest.frame_2.widget_10" above ".tabtest.frame_1.widget_5

        self.buttons = buttons
        self.frames = frames
        self.entries = entries

        self.pack(fill='both')
        root = self._root()
        root.update()
        root.minsize(root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height())



def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = TabTest(root, name='tabtest')
    root.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the tab order in a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687108/how-to-set-the-tab-order-in-a-tkinter-application)

Comment: @PRMoureu - Thanks, but slightly different use case. That was one I found and tested against my needs. Note that it specifically references packing multiple widgets within a single frame, not in multiple frames. When I execute the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6781700/1843248), it works as expected. However, executing it in the same fashion in my example generates the exception I noted.

Comment: it seems to work fine with `new_order = (frames[0], frames[2], frames[1])` or in the same way provided by @Novel

Comment: ...and now that I did that, as-is, you are correct: It does work in the same way. But why doesn't the simple `obj1.lift(obj0)` work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call `lift()` without an argument for all frames in the order you want them:

```
for idx in [0,2,1]:
    frames[idx].lift()
```

Comment: That appears to work. Not an optimum solution, but it will work fine. I would prefer to just be able to execute the lift once.

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the logic, and apply `lower` to the `frames[1]` :

```
frames[1].lower()
```

instead of `frames[2].lift(frames[1])`

Comment: Hmm. Just tried that. What that does is put `frames[1]` first in the tab order, so the first `<Tab>` moves to Widget 5. I may do that, but not certain yet.

Comment: otherwise i found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687108/how-to-set-the-tab-order-in-a-tkinter-application)