# Having trouble with traversal order over tkinter entry fields

Tags: python, tkinter, traversal

So my issue is dealing with tabbing over the entry fields built from tkinter. I'm trying to tab over them in descending order, but the order is reversed. If I Shift+Tab over them, the order is correct, but I'm trying to make it to where I can tab over the entry fields in the correct order.

I thought this had to do with the order you create the entries in, but after messing around with the creation order, I can't seem to figure it out. What am I missing?

Thank you.

I've tried moving around code snippets as I have the entry fields separated into right and left frames. I built the left first then the right, and that's the order I'd like to be able to tab through, but I've also tried creating the right side first to no avail.

```
import tkinter as tk
import re
from tkinter import Label
from typing import Tuple

root = tk.Tk()


class App(tk.Frame):
    # COLOR SETTING AND BACKGROUND IMAGE
    black = "#000000"
    bg_color = "#D4E9D4"

    phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')

    # FONT CONFIGURATION
    font_config: Tuple[str, str] = ("Times New Roman", "12")

    canvas_height = 600
    canvas_width = 1024

    entry_pos_x = 0.30
    entry_pos_y = [0.20, 0.28, 0.36, 0.44, 0.52, 0.60]

    label_pos_x = 0.29
    label_pos_y = [0.21, 0.29, 0.37, 0.45, 0.53, 0.61]

    drop_down_width = 0.40

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        assert isinstance(master, object)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # WINDOW TITLE
        self.winfo_toplevel().title("TITLE")

        # BACKGROUND CANVAS CONFIGURATION
        canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=self.canvas_height, width=self.canvas_width)

        # IMAGE
        canvas.create_image((0, 0), image=self.image)
        canvas.pack(expand="yes", fill="both")

        # LEFT FRAME OBJECTS
        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=self.bg_color)
        self.left_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.8)

        self.left_var = tk.StringVar(self.left_frame)
        self.phone_entry = tk.Entry(self.left_frame)
        self.email_entry = tk.Entry(self.left_frame)
        self.address_entry = tk.Entry(self.left_frame)
        self.last_name_entry = tk.Entry(self.left_frame)
        self.first_name_entry = tk.Entry(self.left_frame)
        self.ethnicity_options = ["Asian", "Black/African", "Caucasian",
                              "Hispanic/Latino", "Native American", "Pacific Islander",
                              "Prefer not to answer"]

        self.ethnic_drop_down = tk.OptionMenu(self.left_frame, self.left_var, *self.ethnicity_options)

    # ***************LEFT**************

    # ENTRY FIELD CONFIGURATION
        self.first_name_entry.config(font=self.font_config)
        self.first_name_entry.place(relx=self.entry_pos_x, rely=self.entry_pos_y[0], relwidth=0.40)
        self.first_name_entry.focus()

        self.last_name_entry.config(font=self.font_config)
        self.last_name_entry.place(relx=self.entry_pos_x, rely=self.entry_pos_y[1], relwidth=0.40)

        self.address_entry.config(font=self.font_config)
        self.address_entry.place(relx=self.entry_pos_x, rely=self.entry_pos_y[2], relwidth=0.40)

        self.email_entry.config(font=self.font_config)
        self.email_entry.place(relx=self.entry_pos_x, rely=self.entry_pos_y[3], relwidth=0.40)

        self.phone_entry.config(font=self.font_config)
        self.phone_entry.place(relx=self.entry_pos_x, rely=self.entry_pos_y[4], relwidth=0.40)

    # DROP_DOWN CONFIGURATION
        ethnic_label = tk.Label(self.left_frame, bg=self.bg_color, text="Ethnicity")
        ethnic_label.config(font=self.font_config)
        ethnic_label.place(relx=self.label_pos_x, rely=self.label_pos_y[5], anchor="e")

    # ETHIC MENU CONFIGURATION
        self.left_var.set(self.ethnicity_options[6])
        self.ethnic_drop_down.config(font=self.font_config)
        self.ethnic_drop_down.place(relx=self.entry_pos_x, rely=self.entry_pos_y[5], relwidth=self.drop_down_width)

        # RIGHT FRAME OBJECTS
        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=self.bg_color)
        self.right_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.8)

        self.right_var = tk.StringVar(self.right_frame)
        self.username_entry = tk.Entry(self.right_frame, font=40)

        # # ***************RIGHT**************
        self.username_entry.place(relx=self.entry_pos_x, rely=self.entry_pos_y[4], relwidth=0.40)

        username_label = tk.Label(self.right_frame,
                              bg=self.bg_color, text="Username")
        username_label.config(font=self.font_config)
        username_label.place(relx=self.label_pos_x, rely=self.label_pos_y[4], anchor="e")


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = App(master=root)
 app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you seen this? [How to set the tab order in a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6687108/7432)

Comment: This code doesn't run. There's an indentation error at the end, and I also get an AttributeError on self.image. Since the image is unrelated to the tab order, I recommend removing it and also removing as many other widgets as you can. When I fix all those errors, the tab order is the same as the order the widgets are created which is the documented behavior.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of code missing because most of it was irrelevant to the problem. It didn't automatically indent when I copy/pasted. Sorry about that. Thanks for sending me to the link though, it helped me figure out the issue, so I appreciate that very much.